EnergyPlus Error Message: reading vertices information incorrectly in IDF file
I have created a basic .idf input for EnergyPlus (EP). All my work and attempts to edit the file have been done in Notepad ++.  My building model is 2 stories with 2 zones and 2 building materials. When I attempt to run the file EP produces a message outlining 7 severe error.
I think all the errors are stemming from the first error shown here:
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][number_of_vertices] - "0" - Expected number greater than or equal to 3.000000
The other errors are:
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][number_of_vertices] - Failed to validate against child schema #0.
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][number_of_vertices] - "0" - Failed to match against any enum values.
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][number_of_vertices] - Failed to validate against child schema #1.
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][number_of_vertices] - Failed to validate against any schemas allowed by anyOf constraint.
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][sun_exposure] - "NoWind" - Failed to match against any enum values.
** Severe  ** [BuildingSurface:Detailed][First_Floor][vertices][3] - Missing required property 'vertex_z_coordinate'.
**  Fatal  ** Errors occurred on processing input file. Preceding condition(s) cause termination.
I did find one error where Wind Exposure had not been included so I corrected that issue. Also I looked at the example files included and saw they listed coordinates in a decimal format so I updated my code to follow this format. I did a line by line check to ensure that I used the same spelling of floors, zones and materials across the code. Below is the revised code. Unfortunately the changes did not fix the errors.
I have included the section of code below. Anyone know where the issue is?
BuildingSurface:Detailed,
    First_Floor,            !- Name of Building Area
    Floor,              !- Surface Type
    Exterior_Floor,         !- Construction Name
    First_Floor_Office_Zone,    !- Zone Name
    Ground,             !- Outside Boundary Condition 
    ,               !- Outside Boundary Condition Object
    NoSun,              !- Sun Exposure
    NoWind,             !- Wind Exposure
    0,              !- View Factor to Ground
    4,              !- Number of Vertices
    0,0,0,              !- Vertex 1
    0,10,0,             !- Vertex 2
    10,10,0,            !- Vertex 3
    10,0,0;             !- Vertex 4
    
BuildingSurface:Detailed,
    Intermediate_Floor,     !- Name of Builidng Area
    Ceiling,            !- Surface Type
    Interior_Floor,         !- Construction Name
    First_Floor_Office_Zone,    !- Zone Name
    Surface,            !- Outside Boundary Condition
    Intermediate_Floor,     !- Outside Boundary Condition Object
    NoSun,              !- Sun Exposure
    NoWind,             !- Wind Exposure
    0,              !- View Factor to Ground
    4,              !- Number of Vertices
    0.0,0.0,3.0,            !- Vertex 1
    0.0,10.0,3.0,           !- Vertex 2
    10.0,10.0,3.0,          !- Vertex 3
    10.0,0.0,3.0;           !- Vertex 4

BuildingSurface:Detailed,
    Second_Floor,           !- Name of Building Area
    Floor,              !- Surface Type
    Interior_Floor,         !-Construction Name
    Second_Floor_Office_Zone,   !- Zone Name
    Surface,            !- Outside Boundary Condition
    Intermediate_Floor,     !- Outside Boundary Condition Object
    NoSun,              !- Sun Exposure
    NoWind,             !- Wind Exposure
    0,              !- View Factor to Ground
    4,              !- Number of Vertices
    0.0,0.0,3.0,            !- Vertex 1
    0.0,10.0,3.0,           !- Vertex 2
    10.0,10.0,3.0,          !- Vertex 3
    10.0,0.0,3.0;           !- Vertex 4
    
BuildingSurface:Detailed,
    Roof,                  !- Name of Building Area
    Roof,                  !- Surface Type
    Exterior_Roof,         !- Construction Name
    Second_Floor_Office_Zone,     !- Zone Name
    Outdoors,              !- Outside Boundary Condition
    ,                      !- Outside Boundary Condition Object
    SunExposed,            !- Sun Exposure
    WindExposed,           !- Wind Exposure
    0,                     !- View Factor to Ground
    4,                     !- Number of Vertices
    0.0,0.0,6.0,                 !- Vertex 1
    0.0,10.0,6.0,                !- Vertex 2
    10.0,10.0,6.0,               !- Vertex 3
    10.0,0.0,6.0;                !- Vertex 4

